# MVC3/CTP5/ViewModel/Master-Detail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, ef-code-first

I am trying to wrangle in the code first approach and I have a gap in understanding here.  I have a collection of posts and files.

```
public class post {
public post(){attachements = new list<files>();}
[key]
public int id{get;set;}
public string title{get;set}
public string body{get;set;}
public virtual ICollection<Files> attachments {get;set;}
}

public class file{
[key]
public int id{get;set;}
public string filename {get;set;}
}
```

And I think I have the ViewModel down with the following

```
public class MyView{
public post post {get;set;}
public list<files> files {get;set;}
public MyView(post p, list<file> f){this.post = p; this.files = f;}
```

Everything works fine for List and Display ... but when I try to create a new post and files it all falls apart.  I've tried using the ViewModel but I am not sure how to add items to the list in the view model.

I created a view based on my 'post' and then have a partial view that uploads files and keeps a list of them in a hidden field I can get everything to work, I am just not sure if that is the elegant solution.

Could someone let me know if I am way off base ... I hope to start the convo and hopefully collect some responses that will be helpful to other noobs.

Comment: SO.com is a good place for specific questions and not so good for conversations.  You first say " it all falls apart. " and then you say "I can get everything to work" so I'm not sure what the question is here.  If you want to know if there is a more efficient technique, post your entire technique.  Simple class declarations aren't meaty enough.

Comment: jfar ... you are correct.  I appologize for the vague description.  What I mean was. If I have a ViewModel that has a Icollection<entity> when I make the "create page" how can I add to the collection.  I was hoping that my simple class declarations would simply demonstrate what i am trying  to accomping.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use the List Model Binding features of MVC:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

For a good guide of how this can all work together:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/